# Testing Input::hasFile in Laravel

Tags: testing, laravel, file-upload, phpunit, facade

I'm using

```
if (Input::hasFile('index')) doSomething();
```

to check if the file was uploaded.

Now I wanna write a PHPUnit test case where the system needs to behave like the "index" file was uploaded.

```
Input::shouldReceive('hasFile')->andReturn(true)
```

does not work.

Also there's a note in laravel docs: You should not mock the Request facade. Instead, pass the input you desire into the call method when running your test.

So maybe this isn't such a great idea after all.

I tried mocking \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile and passing it to my call method but after I define "shouldReceive" for all methods the system is expecting it still doesn't work as I need it to.

Is there any way to test the call so that `Input::hasFile` would return TRUE without uploading an actual file?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you write mock test code. But you may try it in the following way:

```
$mockInput = Mockery::mock('\Illuminate\Http\Request');
$mockInput->shouldReceive('file')->andReturn($my_test_data);
Input::swap($mockInput);
```

Hope this helps.

`file` here is the input name in your form or API to receive uploaded file. You may change it to the name of your parameter.

Comment: Well...I've seen this attempt before asking the question. It didn't work for me. I can't make the "hasFile" method to return true.